# Highlight the latest row in ngx-datable

Tags: angular, ngx-datatable

We have a table created in angular application using ngx-datatable. I wish to highlight the latest row dynamically for 2 seconds. How can we achieve this. Below is the code that has been tried.

```
<ngx-datatable class="material" 
            [rows]="rows" 
            [columnMode]="'force'" 
            [reorderable]="reorderable"
            [rowClass]="getRowClass"
            (activate)="onActivate($event)">
            <ngx-datatable-column name="Cabinet Name" [flexGrow]="1">
                <ng-template let-row="row" ngx-datatable-cell-template>
                    <span class='folder-color'>folder</span>
                    {{ row?.cabinetname }}
                </ng-template>
            </ngx-datatable-column>
</ngx-datatable>
```

```
getRowClass = (row) => {
    console.log('rowClass');
    return {
      'row-color': row.id === 3 ? true: false,
    };
    setTimeout(() => {
      return {
        'row-color': false
      }
    }, 2000);
  };
  rows = [
    { id: 1, name: 'Austin', gender: 'Male', company: 'Swimlane' },
    { id: 2, name: 'Dany', gender: 'Male', company: 'KFC' },
    { id: 3, name: 'Molly', gender: 'Female', company: 'Burger King' },
  ];
  columns = [{ prop: 'name' }, { name: 'Gender' }, { name: 'Company' }];
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8trsx?file=src%2Fmain.ts I have created this demo. Can you please expain bit more about the what row do you wanted to highlighted?

Comment: @GRD For now would like to highlight (apply border to the row from all sides) for the row with id = 3. It should be highlighted for a couple of seconds and then return to normal.

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-m8trsx?file=src%2Fmain.ts Here I have updated some part of code. Is this working as expected now? Let me know. Thanks.

Comment: @GRD thanks for sharing... had to do some changes to your shared code.. but it really helped reaching the desired behavior. Thanks :)

Comment: What type of changes did you make? Thanks.